# str_word_count() without HTML

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm using `str_word_count()` to calculate the number of words in a content from `CKEditor`. the content I get from the CKEditior is an HTML content, and I need to calculate the word count. in MS words I get the word count 328. On the other hand in html tags I get from my content after using `str_word_count()` a 362 words. Is there any way to remove any HTML tags from a php string variable? I tried to use `strip_tags()`, and it gave me 336. is there any way to get the exact word count in PHP ? thank you in advance.

for example this essay entered by a user like this.

> Mixed School or Unisex School
>
> Have you ever think about the impact of mixed schools for students?
>   Most of the schools in the U.S are mixed gender, which mean girls and
>   boys are studying with each other in the same classroom. Some parents
>   wonder about the influences of their child’s in the school either in
>   mixed school or in unisex ones. These influences are not about the
>   education only, the influences about their personality, behavior with
>   the opposite sex and finally their education. In my opinion, I think
>   the unisex schools for teenager’s students are much better than mixed
>   schools, and this conclusion based in many reasons.

and in the MS word the word count is: `107`

in php

> `&nbsp;`
>
> Mixed School or Unisex School
>
> `&nbsp;`
>
> Have you ever think about the impact of mixed schools for students?
>   Most of the schools in the U.S are mixed gender, which mean girls and
>   boys are studying with each other in the same classroom. Some parents
>   wonder about the influences of their child’s in the school
>   either in mixed school or in unisex ones. These influences are not
>   about the education only, the influences about their personality,
>   behavior with the opposite sex and finally their education. In my
>   opinion, I think the unisex schools for teenager’s students are
>   much better than mixed schools, and this conclusion based in many
>   reasons.

and the result: `114`

I'm calculating an extra 7 words for one paragraph essay.

### edit

after using

```
    $text = strip_tags($this->orginal_content);
    $text = str_replace('&nbsp;',"",$text);
    $this->orginal_content_count = str_word_count($text);
```

the result: `112`

I've found 3 spaces

```
        Mixed School or Unisex School       Have you ever think about the impact of mixed schools for students? Most of the schools in the U.S are mixed gender, which mean girls and boys are studying with each other in the same classroom. Some parents wonder about the influences of their child’s in the school either in mixed school or in unisex ones. These influences are not about the education only, the influences about their personality, behavior with the opposite sex and finally their education. In my opinion, I think the unisex schools for teenager’s students are much better than mixed schools, and this conclusion based in many reasons.
```

Comment: More info, such as what HTML tags were left after using `string_tags` would help.

Comment: can you go ahead and use echo $yourstring; and give us the output so we can determine what exactly is being echo'd out so we can tell you how to properly remove it?

Comment: ok. add this $content = str_replace('&nbsp;',"",$content); to your string. essentially you have a non breaking space twice in your string and that should remove those for you. might have to do that twice but usually once is the charm

Comment: it's works but now there are spaces at the beginning and i think the script calculate them as `words`

Comment: see my edit i've attached the result

Comment: it has to do with the functionality of the word count. it counts the spaces. theoretically you could add another $content = str_replace("  ", " ", $content); (2 spaces in first part 1 space in second part.

Comment: if it is double spaced. which should replace double spacing with single spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.

You already know about `strip_tags()`. That's a good start.

You're replacing `&nbsp;` with a space, but that only deals with that single specific entity. You would be better off using PHP's [`html_entity_decode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) which will get rid of all of the entity codes from your string.

If extra spacing is causing you problems, you could try doing `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` to get rid of them. eg:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\s\s+/',' ',$input);
```

This will convert all multiple-whitespace instances into a single space character.

Now your word count should work a little better.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it's Ok now, but there is a small problem now. it the user entered a sentence like this. `The doctor couldn't make the surgery because there was not enough`. the script will read it like this and add 1 word `The doctor couldn&#39;t make`. what i should do now ?

Comment: `html_entity_decode()` should turn the `&#39;` into an apostrophe.